# How to sort such a multidimensional array with array_multisort()?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Let’s say we have an array like that

```
array(2) {
  [2012]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(3) "aaa"
      ["mtime"]=>
      int(1347534106)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(3) "bbb"
      ["mtime"]=>
      int(1346293592)
    }
  }
  [2011]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(3) "ccc"
      ["mtime"]=>
      int(1316753224)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(3) "ddd"
      ["mtime"]=>
      int(1318671936)
    }
  }
}
```

I want this array to be sorted descending by first index (2012,2011[,2010,…]) and every subarray (every value of the root array) sorted descending by mtime values, but I cannot get how to apply array_multisort() to this. I could pass first key as '2012' and then it would be passed as a key of an associative array, but how to sort by mtime then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your toplevel array is `$array`, you can do like this:

```
krsort($array);
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    uasort($arr, 'cmp');
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $b['mtime'] - $a['mtime'];
}

var_dump($array); //to check results
```

that should do what you want.

**Update**: changed ksort for krsort for obtaining the descendin years as OP wanted.

Comment: I was testing right now and wondering why is it upside down :)
Works perfect, but I just wanted to know, is array_multisort() applicable to this example or not? Reading php.net I was sure that this function is kind of ‘the only proper’ to sort multidimensional arrays.